# Can Zombie.js/Phantom.js be used to get HTML of newly open window by window.open?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, zombie.js

I am trying to get html of newly open window after activating a link that uses javascript by zombie.js.

Here is the html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function newin(id)
        {
            var url="page.php?id="+id;
            window.open(url,id,"toolbar=no,location=top,directories=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,hscroll=no,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no,width=1025,height=1250");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:newin(123)">123</a><br/>
        <a href="javascript:newin(234)">234</a><br/>
        <a href="javascript:newin(345)">345</a><br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

The Script I am using is:

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var browser = new Browser();
browser.visit("http://localhost:8000/testpage.html", function () {
    browser.wait(function(){
        var selector = "a[href*='newin']";
        var elements = browser.queryAll(selector);
        for (var e=0;e<elements.length;e++){
            browser.clickLink(elements[e],function(){
                browser.wait(function(){
                    console.log(browser.html());
                });
             });
         }
    });
});
```

I am not able to get HTML of any window.Any ideas what is wrong in this code ? Or is this possible with phantomjs??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I come to know that if a link contains JavaScript directly in the href or action, Zombie seems to understand that as opening a new page like a normal hyperlink would. While the JavaScript is still executed correctly, the DOM is lost as a result of Zombie trying to load the invalid target as a new page.

A problematic link would be e.g.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">test</a>
```

There’s no support for javascript:links, it is still an open issue:

https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/700